# How can I use CMD to create a subfolder in a folder and move every 10 files created there?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

There is a cmd code (see code below). You can't do it in Powershell for I need it in cmd. This code with ffmpeg software slices the video into pieces. The point is, before ffmpeg works I create command **MD folder result_%%i** and put there for each processed file ALL results (video files) of ffmpeg processing: **result_%%i/%%i%03d.mp4**

Question: How to create a subfolder in the folder for each of 10 output slices and put them there? Respectively so, there will be several subfolders in the result_%%i folder.

The subfolder should be numbered as **result_1_%%i** , for example. Thus, the full path to any file will look like this: **result_%%i/result_1_%%i/%%i%03d.mp4**

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  MD result_%%i
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -filter_complex "[0:v]boxblur=40,scale=1080x1920,setsar=1[bg];[0:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=y=(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -x264-params scenecut=0:open_gop=0:min-keyint=72:keyint=72 -c:a aac -preset slow -crf 23 -r 30 -sn -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -f segment -segment_time 14.5 -reset_timestamps 1 result_%%i/%%i%%03d.mp4

)

pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a batch file for this task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  md "result_%%~ni"
  ffmpeg.exe -i "%%i" -filter_complex "[0:v]boxblur=40,scale=1080x1920,setsar=1[bg];[0:v]scale=1080:1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=y=(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -x264-params scenecut=0:open_gop=0:min-keyint=72:keyint=72 -c:a aac -preset slow -crf 23 -r 30 -sn -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -f segment -segment_time 14.5 -reset_timestamps 1 "result_%%~ni\%%~ni%%03d.mp4"
  if not errorlevel 1 set "FolderName=result_%%~ni" & call :MoveFiles
)) & exit /B
:MoveFiles
set "FolderCount=0"
:FolderLoop
set /A FolderCount+=1
set "SlicesFolder=%FolderName%\Slices_%FolderCount%"
md "%SlicesFolder%"
set "FileCount=0"
for %%j in ("%FolderName%\*.mp4") do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if !FileCount! == 10 endlocal & goto FolderLoop
    endlocal
    move "%%j" "%SlicesFolder%\" >nul
    set /A FileCount+=1
)
goto :EOF
```

Let us assume the current directory on starting the batch file contains the movie file `Development & Test(!) 100%.mov`.

The batch file creates the subdirectory `result_Development & Test(!) 100%` in the current directory.

Then the batch file runs `ffmpeg.exe` which creates in this directory the files:

```
Development & Test(!) 100%_001.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_002.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_003.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_004.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_005.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_006.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_007.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_008.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_009.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_010.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_011.mp4
Development & Test(!) 100%_012.mp4
```

The subroutine `MoveFiles` creates in `result_Development & Test(!) 100%` two more subdirectories and moves the files into them. So the final directory structure is:

- **result_Development & Test(!) 100%**

  - **Slices_1**

    - Development & Test(!) 100%_001.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_002.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_003.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_004.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_005.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_006.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_007.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_008.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_009.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_010.mp4
  - **Slices_2**

    - Development & Test(!) 100%_011.mp4
    - Development & Test(!) 100%_012.mp4

The command `exit /B` can be replaced by `goto SliceDone` with the label `:SliceDone` below the posted code and more command lines with `endlocal` as last command line.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>nul`.
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explaining the operator `&`.
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)